# Performance Counters on Web Service Operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, performancecounter

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service communicating with a winform client over netTCP.

The WCF service was hosted in IIS a long time ago and at this point I could see every operation of the WCF service in the performance counter monitor(performanceCounters="All"). This made it easy to see what operations was most used.

I need these performance counters again but this time I can´t find them in performance monitor even while the performanceCounters is set to "All"?

What do I need to do to bring them back?

*The WCF service demands login to use its operations but the login is done by me manually, this means that the user first calls the Login operation with username and password and if its not correct data, then a securityException will be thrown. So nothing advanced.*

Comment: Have you tried these settings? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431917/WCF-Service-Performance-Monitoring-using-Perfmon

Comment: Have you added any WCF extension points e.g. IOperationInvoker? Are you self hosting e.g. Windows Service or IIS? What identity is the service running under? Have you checked event logs? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I can´t see that the article does anymore then I have done. It does not talk about performancecounters for the individual webservice methods at all?

Comment: @PetarVučetin the WCF service is hosted in a Windows Service, I supose you would call this selfhosting. The project are not using IOperationInvoker at all right now, should I implement it? And if so, where? Is it maybe on the service itself? Event logs says nothing related to my WCF service. I have tried first starting the service and then after all counters is registered(have some manually added) start the performandce monitor but still now webmethods. Maybe its not possible outside the IIS?

Comment: @Banshee - I don't think you actually read it... It seems clear to me that you can see the individual services, for instance look at this image: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/431917/ServiceModelOperation.png

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch yes the instances is one thing, this is working just fine. The problem is that I cant find the performance counters for all the webmethods individually. So what Im looking for are a list of all the webmethods within Performance monitor for a given service where I can listen and see how many calls and so on each webmethod get.

Comment: @Banshee - you can see each individual method in that screenshot.  ie.  IServ14.GetData, and IServer14.GetDataUsing (these are the names of the default WCF methods for the default WCF Template).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch sorry, you are right! But Im not getting this for my service? I do get the instance under my manually created(from c# code) performance counter group but the ServiceModelOperation, ServiceModelEndpoint and ServiceModelService do not got any instances at all?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I restarted Performance monitor and after this I get one instance under the ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0 but still no instances under the other 2? I have also tried to run a couple of webmethods and then check performance monitor but still no instances, I even restarted the performance monitor again but no instances!?

Comment: IMHO, using message inspector or the like to do performance profiling will be a good choice.

Comment: Message inspector is to slow(already tried) and performance profiling are what I am asking about here.

Comment: How many performance counters and/or instances are we talking about?  There is a very real limit to the total number of instances unless you change system-level settings.

Comment: FYI, if you're using WCF, then you are _not_ using WebMethods. The term "WebMethod" refers to a method decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is full of great monitoring tools and extensibility endpoints that you can either utilize or hook into your own solution.

You can definitely got some level of instrumentation out of the box, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098(v=vs.110).aspx this article explains the simple app.config change youll need to publish those metrics.

If you want more detailed information (or simply something that isnt yet provided for you) you can indeed create a IOperationInvoker or an IParamterInspector that is called right before the method is called (in your implemenation) and right after it completes. Ive used this before to add context information on a thread before the method is called, to check the caller is passing parameters that they are authorized to use and to gauge the call performance by simply timestamping before and after the call. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx for a list of extensibility points in the WCF stack. 
Good luck